# Chinese character \cjk within \section{} does not work using pdflatex, + \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, sectioning, pdftex, cjk

Why does the following not work

```
\section{ \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
白居易
\end{CJK}}
```

It works when I use it in the main text, but does not work within `\section{xxx}`.

Same applies to the following case `\section{ \includegraphics[]{image.png}}`

Any advise on how to force the chinese characters in the section using the CJK package and pdflatex ? (I don't want to use xelatex or luatex since they mess up my other settings).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `CJK` environment gloally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}

\section{About 白居易}

some text

\clearpage\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Don't forget `\clearpage` at the end of `CJK` environment. It is about a bug of `CJK` package.

Comment: @RyanSmullyen: If it does help, you could [upvote and accept the answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer).